# opengl causes strange memory access error (with minimal example)

Tags: c++, opengl, memory

I encountered a strange memory access error in combination with opengl in c++.
Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>

void draw(){
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glFlush();
}

int main()
{
  std::string test = "memory access error";

  //init glut, display and so on
  int my_argc = 0;
  glutInit(&my_argc, NULL);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGBA);
  glutInitWindowSize(1280, 1024);
  glutCreateWindow("test");

  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 

  glutDisplayFunc(draw);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 1; 
}
```

It should just draw a blue background, but I get a memory access error after compilation via:

`g++ opengl_test.cpp -o opengl_test -lGL -lglut`

but if `std::string test = "memory access error"` is commented out, everything works as expected ....

Furthermore, if I don't build against -lGL everything is fine, too...

System:
Ubuntu 14.04 - 3.13.0-123-generic
OpenGL 4.5.0
NVIDIA-Treiber 375.66

GDB Output: compiled with `-g3` and `-ggdb`

```
(gdb) b main
Haltepunkt 1 at 0x400d1b: file opengl_test.cpp, line 11.
(gdb) b draw
Haltepunkt 2 at 0x400d01: file opengl_test.cpp, line 5.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /my_opengl/opengl_test

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

**Any ideas?! Can anyone reproduce the error?**
I tested it on another computer and got there also a memory access error ...

Comment: You should post error as well. btw to use `std::string` you need to include `<string>` header.

Comment: And you should find out after which line the error happens.

Comment: Does it work if you pass `glutInit()` proper `argc`/`argv` values?

Comment: Might also need `-lstdc++`.

Comment: @VTT i added #include <string> but the error remains ...

Comment: @tadman i tried to compile with `-lstdc++` but the error remains

Comment: @genpfault also with `argc` and `argv` handed from main function the error occurs

Comment: @BDL it dosen't execute anything, just a memory access error occurs ... even if `std::string test = "memory access error"` is initialized right before `return` an memory access error occurs and not one line is executed ....

Comment: Then please post the full error message.

Comment: @BDL the programm exits just with `memory access error (core dumped)` and I dont know if, how or where I can read the log ...

Comment: Run it with a debugger and figure out on which line this happens.

Comment: @Borgleader I added gdb output in my question ... programm doesn't even reach main() breakpoint?!

Comment: Try adding debug symbols: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html I dont have much experience with gdb however so I cant help you much there. But a debugger should be able to give you more information about the cause of the crash.

Comment: @Borgleader thanks for your help, I'm using GBD the first time and updated my question. I used `-g3` and `-ggdb` options ... which other options should I use?

Comment: has anyone an idea how to fix it?